# Modificar el texto de un boton con xpath

Tags: odoo, odoo10, odoo13

Si quiero modificar el texto de este boton por medio de un xpath

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-wide btn-shadow mb16" >Log in</button>
```

Intente con

```
<xpath expr="//button[hasclass('btn-primary')]" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="text">INGRESAR</attribute>
    <attribute value="text">INGRESAR</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Pero me regresa

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-wide btn-shadow mb16" value="INGRESAR" text="INGRESAR">Log in</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un replace al botón, ya que el texto que quieres modificar no veo forma de modificarlo sin usar javascript.

`<xpath expr="//button[hasclass('btn-primary')]" position="replace"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-wide btn-shadow mb16" >INGRESAR</button> </xpath>`

Saludos.